# How do I align the text in a cell to the top left?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, positioning

I have this code but I want the dates in the left column to be aligned in the top left corner of their cells.

I used `{ L L }` for the left align and it is fine but I used `[t]` for the top align which doesn't work. How do I top align properly?

```
\section*{Work Experience} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{  L{5cm}  L{9cm} }
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
Jun 2016 - Aug 2016 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus maximus ullamcorper eros vel convallis. Integer felis velit, consequat sit amet lectus id, dignissim lobortis enim. Proin eu eleifend lacus, id vestibulum turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.   \\
Jun 2015 - Aug 2015 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porttitor bibendum nisl, quis hendrerit quam finibus nec. Morbi imperdiet congue dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum. \\
Jun 2011 - Aug 2011 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tellus risus, feugiat non vulputate et, congue quis sem. Morbi eleifend, felis vel sollicitudin congue, quam lorem convallis felis.end{tabular}
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the `L` column type defined? Please advise.

Comment: I assume `L` is defined `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`?

Comment: By default, your first column should be aligned to the top. I can't replicate your current problem. Can you provide more detail? Also, your `\arraystretch` redefinition doesn't work in the location where you've put it.

Comment: @Mico sorry forgot to add that, it is as Werner guessed.

Comment: @Werner yeah that `\arraystretch` should be removed, it was an earlier attempt to add spaces between each row in the table.
What more detail do you require too?

Comment: @KO'Reilly: Well, as it stands, I'm unable to replicate your mis-alignment. The cells are all aligned at the top by default. If it's not, you haven't provided enough detail for us to replicate your problem.

Comment: @Werner Apologies, I had defined the `L` column incorrectly which I forgot to include in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear since important detail pertaining to the solution has been omitted from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that by "aligned in the top left corner", you mean that there should be no whitespace to the left of the first column. (You haven't stated how the `L` column type is defined, but I'm reasonably confident it does some kind of left (aka raggedright) alignment.) If this guess is correct, simply replace

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{  L{5cm}  L{9cm} }
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} L{5cm} L{9cm} @{}}
```

The `@{}` elements instruct LaTeX *not* to insert intercolumn whitespace (with a width of `\tabcolsep`) to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column).

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % just a guess...
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0} % this needs to occur before "\begin{tabular}"
\begin{document}

\section*{Work Experience} 
\begin{tabular}{@{} L{3.5cm} L{9cm} @{}}
Jun 2016--Aug 2016 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus maximus ullamcorper eros vel convallis. Integer felis velit, consequat sit amet lectus id, dignissim lobortis enim. Proin eu eleifend lacus, id vestibulum turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.   \\
Jun 2015--Aug 2015 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porttitor bibendum nisl, quis hendrerit quam finibus nec. Morbi imperdiet congue dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum. \\
Jun 2011--Aug 2011 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tellus risus, feugiat non vulputate et, congue quis sem. Morbi eleifend, felis vel sollicitudin congue, quam lorem convallis felis.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it hasn't changed.
My `L` is defined as `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}`. I tried yours but it came up with an undefined control sequence error.
Also I couldn't use the `ragged2e` package for some reason

Comment: @KO'Reilly - By all means, *do not use* the`m` column type: It does middle rather than top alignment! Please also be more specific regarding "I tried your solution but it hasn't changed". E.g., did you try inserting the `@{}` elements? If you can't load the `ragged2e` package, for whatever reason, just change `\RaggedRight` to `\raggedright`.

Comment: Sorry, it was the `m` column type that was messing it all up. That's it working now thank you.
If you don't mind could you tell me how to apply this to a multirow as well?
In this `\multirow{2}{15em}{June} & 1st 
&  5th & 10th \\ ` for example.

Comment: @KO'Reilly - Same answer as before: If you want top-alignment, don't use a method that wlll post the material between rows 1 and 2...